# SQL Server 2005, YTD Monthly count, group by Vendor and include when count is Zero in results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query where I am counting the number of distinct claims for any given client monthly for a YTD report. but what I'm finding is that if the client doesn't have any claims for the year (so each month should show as 0), the client is not showing up at all in the result set. I need the client to show up with a '0' count for the month. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks for any assistance!  :)

My query looks something like:

```
Select c.client_name,
   SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,c2.DateField)WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Jan-13],
   SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,c2.DateField)WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Feb-13],
   SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,c2.DateField)WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Mar-13] etc.....
   From Client c (Nolock)
          inner join claim c2 (nolock)
          on c.client_id = c2.client_id
   Where c.client_id IN (1,3,4,5,7) AND
   c2.DateField between '001-01-2013' and Getdate()
   GROUP BY c.client_name
   ORDER BY c.Client_name
```

My results look like:

```
Client Name|Jan-13|Feb-13|Mar-13|etc.....
abc company|12    |17    |0     |etc......
zzz company|3     |0     |15    |etc...
```

I need the result to look like:

```
Client Name|Jan-13|Feb-13|Mar-13|etc.....
abc company|12    |17    |0     |etc......
rad company|0     |0     |0     |etc.....
zzz company|3     |0     |15    |etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `inner join` which will return you the records from Client table only if there is a matching record in the claim table, replace it with `left outer join` which will give you all records from Client table based on the WHERE clause and joins in the columns from claims table.

This query will join and then filter.

```
Select c.client_name,
   SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,c2.DateField)WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Jan-13],
   SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,c2.DateField)WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Feb-13],
   SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,c2.DateField)WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Mar-13] 
   etc.....
   From Client c (Nolock)
          left outer join claim c2 (nolock)
          on c.client_id = c2.client_id
   Where c.client_id IN (1,3,4,5,7) AND
   ( c2.DateField between '01-01-2013' and Getdate() OR c2.DateField IS NULL )
   GROUP BY c.client_name
   ORDER BY c.Client_name
```

OR this query will filter claim rows before -

```
Select c.client_name,
   SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,c2.DateField)WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Jan-13],
   SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,c2.DateField)WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Feb-13],
   SUM(CASE DATEPART(MONTH,c2.DateField)WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Mar-13] 
   etc.....
   From Client c (Nolock)
          left outer join claim c2 (nolock)
          on c.client_id = c2.client_id 
              AND c2.DateField between '01-01-2013' and Getdate()
   Where c.client_id IN (1,3,4,5,7)
   GROUP BY c.client_name
   ORDER BY c.Client_name
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Lobo, I tried to Left outer join also, but still don't get the the clients with zero records for the year.  The two missing clients didn't have any records to count for 2013 so there isn't anything to count.  But I still need them to show with 0 for each month.  :(

Comment: @Montwill I changed the query. If there is no claim row, `DateField` will be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
Select
    c.client_name,
    Sum(Case Month(c2.DateField) When 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) As [Jan-13],
    Sum(Case Month(c2.DateField) When 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) As [Feb-13],
    Sum(Case Month(c2.DateField) When 3 Then 1 Else 0 End) As [Mar-13],...
From 
    Client c With (Nolock)
        left outer join 
    Claim c2 With (nolock)
        On c.client_id = c2.client_id And
           c2.DateField between '01-01'2013' and GetDate() -- putting it here makes the outer join apply after the filter
Where 
    c.client_id IN (1,3,4,5,7)
Group By
    c.client_name
Order By 
    c.Client_name
```

If not you'll need to left outer join on a subquery that filters claim. Either way the trick is to make sure the left outer join applies after the filter on the outer table.